# How to retain "zebra-striped" table after hiding rows with CSS

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table (with id `table`) where each row has the attribute `data-tagged`, when created (by JS) it is set to `"true"`, and can be set to `"false"` by various functions. I am using the following CSS to hide rows for which the `data-tagged` attribute is `"false"`:

```css
#table tr[data-tagged="false"] {
  display: none;
}
```

And I was using the following CSS to produce a 'zebra-striped' effect, i.e: giving alternating rows a different background colour:

```css
#table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--other-background);
}
```

...until I realised that the row's colours were unchanged as other rows were hidden and un-hidden, which makes sense, since it's still only the even children that are affected by the CSS, so I tried the following selector instead:

```css
#table tr[data-tagged="true"]:nth-of-type(even) { ... }
```

...thinking that this would only affect every other `tr` with attribute `data-tagged` equal to `"true"` (the desired outcome!), but I was wrong, and it made no difference. Is this not do-able in the CSS alone, or is there a solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `:nth-of-class`, which does not exist, but `:nth-child(n of S)` does. Read more [about this selector syntax here](https://www.bram.us/2020/03/16/css-nth-of-class-selector/). (browser support is limited to Safari for now) `:nth-of-type` only "reads" the element type (`tr` in this case), not the selector you specify.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Safari support won't help me, I'm afraid! Until further support is implemented, I guess some messy JS solution would be required.

Comment: I wonder what happens when you do `#table tr[data-tagged="false"]{background-color:unset;display:none;}`..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
#table tr:not([data-tagged="false"]):nth-child(even){background:#fff;}
#table tr:not([data-tagged="false"]):nth-child(odd){background:#eee;}
```

Comment: This seems to work! (with single colons, mind!), thanks!

Comment: @Gentleman_Narwhal are you sure this worked?? maybe try more examples

Comment: @Gentleman_Narwhal non working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kpfxteLj/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, on further investigation it seems to have issues.

Comment: yeah, I fiddled with it some more, doing stuff like `tr[data-tagged="false"]+tr`, but to no avail. Seems like your best bet is to remove it from the DOM using JS afterall.